# How to resolve package conflicts Fedora 33

Tags: installation, package, fedora

After a fresh installation of Fedora 33, I observed these errors:

> Transaction error: file /usr/lib64/libldacBT_abr.so.2.0.2.3 from ldacbt-2.0.2.3-7.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file of package libldac-2.0.2.3-7.fc33.x86_64

> file /usr/lib64/libldacBT_enc.so.2.0.2.3 from installation of ldacbt-2.0.2.3-7.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libldac-2.0.2.3-7.fc33.x86_64

I tried to remove the conflicting files, but noticed this:

> Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: gnome-shell

How do I solve this?

---

PS: messages translated from Portuguese to English.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo dnf config-manager --save --setopt=unitedrpms\*.priority=100

sudo dnf --allowerasing --disablerepo unitedrpms\* distro-sync
```

Provided by [kekorcringewithrms](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/lp6np0/dnf_shits_the_bed_when_trying_to_update_libldac/) from [Fedora Discussions — Can’t upgrade pipewire due to problems with fdk-aac-free, libldac and ldacbt conflicts](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/cant-upgrade-pipewire-due-to-problems-with-fdk-aac-free-libldac-and-ldacbt-conflicts/11903/3)